# Setting up more Virtual Hosts on Webmin

Tags: vps, webmin

i bought VPS and i installed 3 websites. All websites are loading files from one directory( but i set the different while i was creating ).

After putting DNS without making Virtual Hosts, site already loads default web site(first one), after creating virtual host, still the same.

```
<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot /home/svezatebe-online.com/www/
ServerName svezatebe-online.com
<Directory "/home/svezatebe-online.com/www/">
allow from all
Options FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
ServerAlias www.svezatebe-online.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *>
ServerName wasdlife.com
<Directory /home/wasdlife.com/www>
allow from all
Options None
</Directory>
ServerAlias www.wasdlife.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot /home/online-vesti.net/www
ServerName online-vesti.net
<Directory "/home/online-vesti.net/www">
allow from all
Options None
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider some examples from: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html especialy try to adjust your config according to example below:

```
# Ensure that Apache listens on port 80
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/example1"
    ServerName www.example.com

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/example2"
    ServerName www.example.org

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

For testing you can try to do a quick changes in your hosts file to try localy instead of having to do a DNS changes like mentioned at the link above:

> Creating virtual host configurations on your Apache server does not
>   magically cause DNS entries to be created for those host names. You
>   must have the names in DNS, resolving to your IP address, or nobody
>   else will be able to see your web site. You can put entries in your
>   hosts file for local testing, but that will work only from the machine
>   with those hosts entries.